# Showing that $I-A$ is non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-equations

> If $A \in M_n(R) $ with $A^3=0$, show that $I - A$ is non-singular with $(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2$.

How could I approach this?

Comment: I tried to prove that (I-A)*(I+A+A^2) = I but my result was 0=I

Comment: What does it mean that the product of $(I - A)$ with another matrix is the identity matrix? (What is the definition of (non-)singularity?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $(I-A)(I + A + A^2) = I + A + A^2 - A - A^2 - A^3 = I - A^3 = I$ since $A^3 = 0$

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I mistakingly thought I^2=0 when my notes say otherwise. I see my mistake now.

Comment: Of course. Notice that $I$ is functioning as $1$ here.

Comment: Thank you, it definitely looks a lot clearer now that I see my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For any martices $A,B$,

If $\ A B=I$, $A=B^{-1}  \&  B=A^{-1}$

$\ (I-A)(I+A+A^2)=I^3-A^3$ as $AI=IA=A$

Since $A^3=0$, $(I-A)(I+A+A^2)=I$

Thus, $(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2$.